# Trouble displaying output of countdown difference Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, countdown

I am trying to output the difference of two different dates, which are todays date and the date the user selects from the form. I am able to alert the difference, but for some reason, the form won't go away when I click submit. Here is the JS:

```js
//variable to push the option tag into the array
const years = []

for (let yearsLoop = 2021; yearsLoop <= 2031; yearsLoop++) {
  years.push(`<option value="${yearsLoop}">${yearsLoop}</option>`)
    
}

//variable to push the option tag into the array
const days = []

for (let daysLoop = 1; daysLoop <= 31; daysLoop++) {
    days.push(`<option value="${daysLoop}">${daysLoop}</option>`)
}

//variable to push the option tag into the array
const months = [
  'January', 
  'February', 
  'March', 
  'April', 
  'May', 
  'June', 
  'July', 
  'August', 
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
]

for (let monthLoop = 0; monthLoop < 12; monthLoop++) {
  months.push(`<option value="${months[monthLoop]}">${months[monthLoop]}</option>`)
}


//Displays the web form
const timeForm = `<form id='form'>
<label for="title">Title</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Put in a title for your desired day" id="title" class="text-class" name="title"><br>
<label for="year">Year</label>
<select id="year" name="year">
${years}
</select>
<br>
<label for="day">Day</label>
<select id="day" name="day">
${days}
</select>
<br>
<label for="month">Month</label>
<select id="month" name="month">
${months}
</select>
<br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`


//Display the web form on the HTML
const $timeForm = document.getElementById('form-style')
$timeForm.innerHTML += timeForm

const $buttonSubmit = document.getElementById('submit')


//Function used to display the countdown
function displayTime () {
  //Change the h3 text
  document.getElementById('primary-sub').innerHTML = "Countdown to:"

  //Display the output of the title inputed by the user
  let $textValue = document.getElementById('title').value
  
  document.getElementById('timer-title').innerHTML = `<h2>${$textValue}</h2><br> <h3>is</h3>`
  $displayTime.innerHTML = days + 'd' + ': ' + hours + 'h' + ': ' + minutes + 'm' + ': ' + seconds + 's'

  //Getting our user input
  const userMonth = document.getElementById('month').value
  const userDay = document.getElementById('day').value
  const userYear = document.getElementById('year').value

  //Concatenating all of the users inputs into one variable
  const userDate = new Date(userMonth + ' ' + userDay + ',' + '' + userYear)
  const today = new Date()
  

  //Here we will calculate the difference between the two dates
  const difference = userDate - today

  //Convert them from ms to days, hours, minutes, and seconds
  const days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
  const hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
  const minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))
  const seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)

  alert (days + 'd' + ': ' + hours + 'h' + ': ' + minutes + 'm' + ': ' + seconds + 's')
  const $displayTime = document.getElementById('display-countdown')
  

  //Get rid of the original form
  $timeForm.innerHTML = ""
  $timeForm.style.display = 'none'
   
  
}


$buttonSubmit.addEventListener('click', displayTime)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: rgb(124, 196, 255);
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 #form-style {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 132);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #6e6e6e;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}



h1, h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h2{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: lighter;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(124, 196, 255);
    float: left;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

select {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
    .container {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 70rem) {
    .container {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='container'>
    <h1>Countdown Timer App</h1>
    <h3 id = 'primary-sub'>Input a day and view the countdown from today's date</h3>
    <div id='form-style'>
        <div id='form'></div>
    </div>

    <div id="timer-title">
        <div id='display-countdown'></div>
    </div>

 </div>   
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an error that you can see briefly when you click the submit button. If you change it to `button type="button"`, you can see that it was telling you that you were referencing `$displayTime` before you declared it. After clearing that, it said that you were referencing `days` before declaring that.

Moving those lines seems to solve the issue.

Also, since you aren't actually submitting form data anywhere, `button type="text"` is appropriate.

Lastly, it's not entirely clear why your main form content is being dynamically created. Why not just have that written as static HTML and then just update the `option` elements?

```js
//variable to push the option tag into the array
const years = []

for (let yearsLoop = 2021; yearsLoop <= 2031; yearsLoop++) {
  years.push(`<option value="${yearsLoop}">${yearsLoop}</option>`)
}

//variable to push the option tag into the array
const days = []

for (let daysLoop = 1; daysLoop <= 31; daysLoop++) {
    days.push(`<option value="${daysLoop}">${daysLoop}</option>`)
}

//variable to push the option tag into the array
const months = [
  'January', 
  'February', 
  'March', 
  'April', 
  'May', 
  'June', 
  'July', 
  'August', 
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
]

for (let monthLoop = 0; monthLoop < 12; monthLoop++) {
  months.push(`<option value="${months[monthLoop]}">${months[monthLoop]}</option>`)
}


//Displays the web form
const timeForm = `<form id='form'>
<label for="title">Title</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Put in a title for your desired day" id="title" class="text-class" name="title"><br>
<label for="year">Year</label>
<select id="year" name="year">
${years}
</select>
<br>
<label for="day">Day</label>
<select id="day" name="day">
${days}
</select>
<br>
<label for="month">Month</label>
<select id="month" name="month">
${months}
</select>
<br>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`


//Display the web form on the HTML
const $timeForm = document.getElementById('form-style')
$timeForm.innerHTML += timeForm

// Must be before the function that uses it
const $displayTime = document.getElementById('display-countdown');

//Function used to display the countdown
function displayTime () {
  //Change the h3 text
  document.getElementById('primary-sub').innerHTML = "Countdown to:"

  //Display the output of the title inputed by the user
  let $textValue = document.getElementById('title').value
  
  document.getElementById('timer-title').innerHTML = `<h2>${$textValue}</h2><br> <h3>is</h3>`

  //Getting our user input
  const userMonth = document.getElementById('month').value
  const userDay = document.getElementById('day').value
  const userYear = document.getElementById('year').value

  //Concatenating all of the users inputs into one variable
  const userDate = new Date(userMonth + ' ' + userDay + ',' + '' + userYear)
  const today = new Date()
  
  //Here we will calculate the difference between the two dates
  const difference = userDate - today

  //Convert them from ms to days, hours, minutes, and seconds
  const days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
  const hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
  const minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))
  const seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)

  // Must be after the above declarations
  $displayTime.innerHTML = days + 'd' + ': ' + hours + 'h' + ': ' + minutes + 'm' + ': ' + seconds + 's'

  alert (days + 'd' + ': ' + hours + 'h' + ': ' + minutes + 'm' + ': ' + seconds + 's')

  //Get rid of the original form
  $timeForm.innerHTML = "";
  $timeForm.style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', displayTime);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: rgb(124, 196, 255);
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 #form-style {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 132);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #6e6e6e;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}



h1, h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h2{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: lighter;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(124, 196, 255);
    float: left;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255)
}

select {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
    .container {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 70rem) {
    .container {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='container'>
    <h1>Countdown Timer App</h1>
    <h3 id = 'primary-sub'>Input a day and view the countdown from today's date</h3>
    <div id='form-style'>
        <div id='form'></div>
    </div>
    <div id="timer-title">
        <div id='display-countdown'></div>
    </div>
 </div>   
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```